# Spark 2.1.0 - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to use spark-submit with Spark 2.1.0 to read Avro files.

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
       <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-avro_2.10</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>    
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.8</version>
</dependency>    
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
        at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anon$1.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:205)
        at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:205)
        at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I checked similar posts and tried various options, but unable to resolve the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the problem is mixing Scala 2.10 (`spark-avro_2.10`) and Scala 2.11 libraries. If you use Scala 2.11 it should be:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-avro_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The spark version is 2.1.0. That was why I had used spark-avro_2.10.

Comment: Dint realize that Spark 2.1.0 uses Scala 2.11 by default. Using spark-avro_2.11 resolved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a ton, by changing to spark-avro_2.11, the all day taking, painful issue got resolved :)